# "ImportError: Couldn't import Django" using heroku, but not while running locally

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm running into a weird issue when trying to deploy my Django project using Heroku.

I meticulously followed all of the steps, which can be found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#django-applications-on-heroku

Right now, I'm at the last step of migrating my database. To do this, I run

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Which results in the exception error "Couldn't import Django"

However, when I run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

everything works fine.

I have absolutely no idea why Django is not importing using Heroku, and haven't resolved the issue after a few hours of troubleshooting. Here is the repo with my code: https://github.com/tonypedraza/luispedraza/tree/master/luispedraza

Please let me know if I can give any more information.

Thank you!!!!

Comment: try running this command and see if Django is listed: `heroku run pip freeze`

Comment: Hi, @n8sty I tried to run the command but I received a bash pip command not found error. I tried installing pip with `heroku run python get-pip.py` but I received a file not found error for get-pip.py. Have you run the heroku command before?

Comment: I just ran that command on one of my Django projects and it worked fine. Do you have a runtime.txt file in the root directory of your project?

Comment: Just figured it out, answer posted below. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. Turns out that my heroku app wasn't created while I was in my virtualenv. For anyone experiencing a similar issue, I discovered this by running the following code:

```
$ heroku run bash
$ python
$ import sys
$ sys.path
```

This showed me that heroku was pointing to the dependencies in my system directories, not the ones in my virtualenv. To resolve, I deleted the app and created a new one while in my virtualenv. I'm sure you could change the sys.path to point to the correct directories, but I decided to just restart the project since I had just started it.

Comment: Hi please I am getting this error but still don't know how to figure it out

Comment: @olar19 Did you try the above answer? Are you getting the exact error this post is about or is there more information?